# I am getting the date and revenue_rates_usd columns, but when I try to get range between two dates, I get and error

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

```
pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM usd_rates;", conn)

   id        date                                  revenue_rates_usd
0  93  2021-07-23  {'AED': 3.673, 'AFN': 79.600004, 'ALL': 103.8,...
1  94  2021-07-24  {'AED': 3.673, 'AFN': 79.600004, 'ALL': 103.8,...
```

```
pd.read_sql("SELECT date as date, revenue_rates_usd ->> 'SAR' AS SAR FROM usd_rates;", conn)

         date       sar
0  2021-07-23  3.750918
1  2021-07-24  3.750712
```

```
pd.read_sql("SELECT date as date, revenue_rates_usd ->> 'SAR' AS SAR WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-07-23' AND '2021-07-24', FROM usd_rates';", conn)
```

Error = Execution failed on sql 'SELECT date as date, revenue_rates_usd ->> 'SAR' AS SAR WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-07-23' AND '2021-07-24', FROM usd_rates';': syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...R WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-07-23' AND '2021-07-24', FROM usd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the "From" you have a comma (,) and the "From" is after that "Where", probably that is the problem.

pd.read_sql("SELECT date as date, revenue_rates_usd ->> 'SAR' AS SAR FROM usd_rates WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-07-23' AND '2021-07-24';", conn)

Comment: No it not, I tried but still there's an error :/